# Variables and wildcards in batch and cmd.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to search all drives for a file name. When using the `dir` command alone all goes well:

```
C:\>dir /s C:\*blabla*
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2AB1-3FBD

  Directory of C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop

 02/08/2016  11:21                 0 blabla.txt
           1 File(s)              0 bytes

 Total Files Listed:
           1 File(s)              0 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  28?369?825?792 bytes free
```

But when using it on a loop it fails:

```
FOR /F "skip=1 delims=" %x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do dir /s %x*blabla*

*blabla* Administrator\Desktop>dir /s A:       
The device is not ready.

*blabla* Administrator\Desktop>dir /s C:       
Volume in drive C has no label.
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this. Am I reading correctly that the only line that appears when `dir /s C:` is called is "Volume in drive C has no label" or is there more?

Comment: try _FOR /F "skip=1 delims= " %x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do dir /s %x\\*blabla*_. the _delims_ has a space as an additional token. also I added a backslash in _%x\\*blabla*_  for _logicaldisk get caption_ returns only drivename and colon, not the backslash

Comment: this is better `FOR /F "skip=1 delims= " %x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do echo(%x | find ":">NUL && dir /s %x\*blabla*`

Comment: Try with this: `for /F "skip=1" %X in ('wmic LogicalDisk GET Caption') do for /F %Y in ("%X") do dir /S "%Y\*blabla*"`; nested another `for /F` loop to avoid artefacts resulting from conversion of the Unicode output of the `wmic` command...

Comment: Is the loop output you showed really complete, or is there more?

Comment: You can try also this command `Where` just type `Where /?`

Comment: Hackoo, where works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, plus great ideas to other scripts.

Where is the answer I was looking for:

```
C:\>FOR /F "skip=1 delims= " %x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do @where /R %x *blabla* 2>NULL
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\blabla.txt
```

Comment: note that `where` looks only in the folders of the `%path%` variable. If your file is somewhere else, you need one of the `dir` solutions (I'd add the `/b` switch)